# Create HashTable in Haskell

Tags: haskell, hashtable

I want to create a HashTable in Haskell, insert hash values inside and look up in this HashTable.

I found this [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.5.1.0/docs/Data-HashTable.html)  but I just started Haskell and therefore I don't really know how to ue these functions.

If some of you could show me some lines of code it would be perfect.

Comment: I agree with @Ingo, learn the language, then try to make a HashTable, because it's a fairly complicated data structure.  Its also a bit more difficult to get it efficient in a language like Haskell if you don't know your way around the language and concepts of FP.  Check out the Learn You a Haskell tutorial and then work through Real World Haskell (both are available online for free), together they make a pretty good introduction to the language.

Answer (score 18):

I second Ingo's comment about starting with something simpler.  However, I'll break down a few things in a bit of detail.

First of all, I assume you've installed the latest [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/).  In the website for the Platform there is [a page with collected documentation for the libraries included with it](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/frames.html).  Any library that's not in that page would be something you'd need to install separately.

The Platform does include `Data.HashTable`, so you don't need to install anything, but if you look at [the latest Platform's documentation on it](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Data-HashTable.html), you'll see that it's deprecated and going to be removed soon.  So I would not use that module.

The Haskell Platform comes with the two most popular Haskell implementations of a map/dictionary data structure:

- [`Data.Map`](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-Map.html).  (Most of the documentation for this is in [`Data.Map.Lazy`](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/Data-Map-Lazy.html).)  This implements a map as a kind of balanced search tree, which means that the keys need to be an ordered type—a type that implements the `Ord` class.  A lot of the built-in Haskell types already implement this class, so this would probably be your easiest choice at first.
- The `Data.HashMap` module hierarchy, with two variants; [`Data.HashMap.Lazy`](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/packages/unordered-containers-0.2.3.0/doc/html/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html) would be a good starting point.  This implements maps as a kind of hash table, so the keys need to implement the [`Hashable`](http://www.haskell.org/platform/doc/2013.2.0.0/frames.html) class.  This class is newer and not as popular as `Ord`, so often you might need to implement this class for your key types.

So `Data.Map` is the easier type to use.  But to use it effectively you're going to need to understand a few things beside the most basic language constructs:

1. How to import a module in a source file.
2. How to use qualified imports—`Data.Map` has function names that collide with many of the built-in ones in Haskell, which requires some special syntax.
3. How to load a module into the ghci interpreter.
4. How to compile a project that uses the `containers` library where `Data.Map` lives (using the `cabal` tool).

Once you have that down, the easiest way to build a map is from a list of key/value pairs:

```
module MyModule where

import Data.Map (Map)             -- This just imports the type name
import qualified Data.Map as Map  -- Imports everything else, but with names 
                                  -- prefixed with "Map." (with the period).

-- Example: make a Map from a key/value pair
ages :: Map String Integer
ages = Map.fromList [("Joe", 35), ("Mary", 37), ("Irma", 16)]
```

A few examples on how to use maps:

```
-- Example: look up somebody and return a message saying what their age is.
-- 'Nothing' means that the map didn't have the key.
findAge :: String -> String
findAge name = case Map.lookup name ages of
                 Nothing  -> "I don't know the age of " ++ name ++ "."
                 Just age -> name ++ " is " ++ show age ++ " years old."

-- Example: make a map with one extra entry compared to `ages` above.
moreAges :: Map String Integer
moreAges = Map.insert "Steve" 23 ages

-- Example: union of two maps.
evenMoreAges :: Map String Integer
evenMoreAges = Map.union moreAges anotherMap
    where anotherMap = Map.fromList [("Metuselah", 111), ("Anuq", 3)]
```

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to Ingo's answer, consider using the purely function [`Data.Map`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/containers/Data-Map.html).

```
 import qualified Data.Map as M

 myMap :: M.Map Int String
 myMap = M.fromList $ zip [1..10] ['a'..'j']

 insertedMap :: M.Map Int String
 insertedMap = M.insert 11 "fizzbuzz" oldMap

 at11 :: Maybe String
 at11 = M.lookup 11 insertedMap
```

Then you can use `M.lookup`, `M.insert`, and many other functions to modify/query the map. This datastructure is also purely functional/persistant (notice how IO is nowhere in the types). That means that we can do something like

```
  let newMap = M.insert key val oldMap
  in M.union oldMap otherMap
```

See how we can still use the older version of the map even after inserting something? That's "persistance", we never destroy the older versions of our data structure.

Comment: With the implementation given, myMap will have signature `myMap :: M.Map Int Char`

Answer (score 4):

Just so to avoid someone calling the haskell community arrogant, here is a short break down of the first function you'll need:

```
new :: (key -> key -> Bool) -> (key -> Int32) -> IO (HashTable key val)
```

This tells us the following: to create a HashTable for a specific key type `key` you need to pass a function that checks equality on keys, and a function that computes a hash value for keys. So, if `eq` and `hashit` would be the desired functions, the following:

```
new eq hashit
```

gives you an empty HashTable in the IO-Monad.

An easier way could be to create a HashTable from a list using one of the predefined hash functions:

```
 fromList hashInt [(42, "forty-two"), (0, "zero")]
```